# 16 bits-only precision in Swing text draw on Linux JVM

Tags: java, linux, swing, jvm, rendering

I came across a strange display behaviour when printing text with Swing [`g2d.drawString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#drawString-java.lang.String-int-int-) with one huge coordinate:

```
static public void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    
    JPanel p = new JPanel() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g1) {
            Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)g1;
            g.drawString(" XX-XXXX-XX ", 0     , 16     );
            g.drawString(" XX-XXXX-XX ", 50    , 1179664);
        }
    };
    p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120, 120));
    
    f.getContentPane().add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

When the above quick'n'dirty code is run, the first call to `drawString()` should display the string, but the second one shouldn't (`y` value way too big for the panel size).
Both values `16` and `1179664` where chosen so both texts perfectly overlap to prove the position is the same.

On **Linux** with **OpenJDK 17** and **Oracle JDK 8**, the huge y coordinate 1179664 is rendered at position 16:

[image: On Linux, small and big coordinates render at the same position]

But on **Windows** with **OpenJDK 18** and **Oracle JDK 8** it is rendered correctly (i.e. not rendered because very much outside of displayable area):

[image: On Windows, small coordinates render but big one does not]

I tracked down the faulty code down to `sun.java2d.xr.XRBackendNative.XRenderCompositeTextNative()` where  `srcY` has a correct value but it interpreted incorrectly: 1179664 is `0x12_0010` which is indeed `16` when truncated to 16-bits.

AFAIK the 16-bits limitation is not mentioned in the documentation so it seems to be a bug in the Linux JVM (or at least an inconsistency with the Windows version) so should I report it or is there a workaround I should be using (apart from the obvious coordinate test)?

Comment: "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[*Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callbacks). See also [*Initial Threads*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: @trashgod yes I missed that. It's included in the "quick'n'dirty" part ;). I edited it anyway.

Comment: I'm a little curious if anything changes; wrap-around seems plausible, but clipping should work.

Comment: You forgot to make the call `super.paintComponent(g1);` inside the `paintComponent` method. I don't know if it is related, but you can try this.

Comment: @trashgod good catch about the clipping! Definitely something to look into, and check perdormace-wise.

Comment: @gthanop it doesn't change anything. The behavior is not consistent between JVM flavors.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap-around seems plausible, but clipping should work. As this appears to be platform dependent, I've recapitulated your example below to eliminate some common problems and display version information. Adjust the slider to test the wrap-around hypothesis.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Shape;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/q/73040491/230513
 */
public class ClipTest {

    private int i = 18; // 16 + i * 0x10000 = 1179664

    public void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame(String.valueOf(i));
        JPanel p = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
                super.paintComponent(graphics);
                Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) graphics;
                Shape olc = g.getClip();
                g.setClip(new Rectangle(getSize())); // Clip on panel size
                g.drawString(" XX-XXXX-XX ", 0, 16);
                g.drawString(" XX-XXXX-XX ", 50, 16 + i * 0x10000);
                g.setClip(olc);
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(120, 120);
            }
        };
        f.add(new JLabel(System.getProperty("os.name")
            + " v" + System.getProperty("os.version")
            + "; Java v" + System.getProperty("java.version")),
            BorderLayout.NORTH);
        f.add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JSlider slider = new JSlider(0, 0x2000, i);
        slider.addChangeListener((e) -> {
            i = slider.getValue();
            f.setTitle(String.valueOf(i));
            p.repaint();
        });
        f.add(slider, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new ClipTest()::display);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried and got the problem for values up to 8192 (0x2000). Above that the problem disappears.

Comment: Thank you; on MacOS 12 with Java 17 LTS, I see it only when `i == 0`; please don't hesitate to edit this answer as needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes, when `i` is 0 then `y` is 16 so it prints as expected. I think the problem comes with the Linux JVM. I'll see of I can check the source code somewhere...

Comment: Is there another JVM available for your distribution?

Comment: There probably are, but I'd rather stay with OpenJDK. I can always make a boundary check in my methods anyway. I'll get back to you when I get a chance to try the clipping. Thanks for following up!

Comment: Well, setting a clip region to the panel size doesn't make it better :/ (see the edited code). I guess I'll fill up a bug in OpenJDK Linux flavor...